# MS Access Union between Columns

Tags: ms-access

I have a table containing three columns with policy # in 2016,17 & 18.
There are a couple of types of rows as a result:

1. policy in force in all three years(have the same policy # in the three-column)
2. policy terminated in 2016 (only have policy # in 2016 column)
3. policy started in 2017 didn't terminate (have policy # in 2017 &18)
4. policy starts in 2018 (have policy # only in 2018)

Let's say there are 1000 rows in this table

Then I tried to use the union function(2016 union with 2017, then union with 2018) in MS access to create a single column containing all the distinct policy#.
However, the resulting distinct is less than the 1000 rows in the original table, which I think they suppose to match.

Any thought on what is causing this? Or it is supposed to shrink after the union?

Many thanks!

Comment: A UNION query should result in more than the original 1000 rows.  If you are actually concatenating fields, then clarify. You should edit question to show attempted SQL statement. Table structure is not normalized.

Comment: That's the problem with poor database/table design. You should not have a column for each year, but  should have a row for each year instead. That would make what you're trying to do very simple, but the poor design makes it complicated. You should redesign your table to store the data properly.

Answer (score 0):

The UNION operator, by its definition, removes duplicates. You can use UNION ALL to keep them all.

To get the unique list of policy numbers use:

```
SELECT p2016 as PolicyNo FROM MyTable
UNION
SELECT p2017 as PolicyNo FROM MyTable
```

But to get them all (duplicates preserved) use:

```
SELECT p2016 as PolicyNo FROM MyTable
UNION ALL
SELECT p2017 as PolicyNo FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Using UNION *does* remove duplicates within each 'set'.  "If a policy No, say, P1, occurs twice in p2016 (and not in p2017), you will have it twice." is not correct.  With your first SELECT statement, P1 will occur only once.  Using UNION removes all duplicate rows.

Comment: I stand corrected; I will update, thanks!